# Create an array of string to run tests over them with string related functions in C

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, string-literals

I am trying to understand what is wrong with my code and my understanding of pointers, arrays and string in C.

I tried to create an array of strings, to be able to loop over it and to test any functions that take a string as a parameter.
In this case, i'm trying to check my private implantation of `memset` called `Memset`.

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/*First Try, did not work: */

/*const char * strings_array[] = {*/
/*    "First string",*/
/*    "213123Second_string3",*/
/*    "",*/
/*    "-3",*/
/*    "s",*/
/*};*/

/* Second try, also does not work: */

const char **strings_array = (char *[]){"a", "b", "c"};

int main () 
{

    while(*strings_array)
    {
    char *string = strings_array;
    printf( "Before Memset, target is \"%s\"\n", *string );
    if (NULL == Memset(*string, '$', 4))
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Memset failed!\n");
    }
    printf( "After Memset, target is \"%s\"\n\n", *string );
    
    ++strings_array;
    }
return (0);
}
```

I know that a `string` in C is not a `type` but a `char *`.
But it is also a `string literal`, which means I can't change it, and can only read it.

That's why it's not working?
Because I'm passing it to `Memset` and `Memset` tries to change it while it can not be changed because it's a string literal?

This is my implantation of my `Memset` function:

```
void *Memset(void *str, int c, size_t n)
{
        unsigned char *string = str;
        
        if (NULL == str)
        {
            return (NULL);
        }
        
        while(n > 0)
        {
            *string++ = (unsigned char) c;
            --n;
        }

    return (str);
}
```

Comment: As you say: you can't apply `memset` to a string literal. One way around is to use a 2D array instead of an array of pointers. Or if you must use an array of pointers, allocate memory for and copy the data, such as with `strdup()`.

Comment: `char *string = strings_array;` should be `char *string = *strings_array;`, it should also be noted that this is an infinite loop, for it to stop you need to null terminate `strings_array`

Comment: @WeatherVane But we do pass `string literals` to functions like `memset`.. I mean I can write `char str[50]` and `strcpy(str,"This is a Memset test")` and send `str` to `memset` and it will work. So why can't it be the same with array of string that generate the same thing as `str` in my example above.

Comment: But `str[50]` is not a string literal. `"This is a Memset test"` is the string literal, which is copied into the array. That does not make the array a string literal, and `memset` will behave the same whether or not you previously copied data into the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane Got ya. So if i'll crate a 2D array like people mentioned here in the comments, I'll basically will create lots of strings as `str[50]` for example?

Comment: In the answer from dbush the strings can be accessed as `strings_array[0]` thru `strings_array[4]`.

Comment: so in the end, there is no way to me to access, change or pass and work with structs array as pointers? I can't do pointer  arithmetic as I wanted to do.

Comment: arrays aren't pointers, you can't increment a an array, you need to use a pointer to iterate through it.

Comment: Please study the two linked duplicates. This has been answered many times before. The TL;DR is that `char str[50] = "foo";` makes a copy of the string literal and the array str is in read/write memory.

Comment: Of course you can. If you pass `strings_array[4]` to a function, it decays to a pointer.

Comment: @Lundin I know. I did write it in my post. I'm asking here something else about passing it as an array to a function that accepts `strings`. I personally don't think it's a duplicated question.

Comment: As you say yourself, you can't pass it to such a function, because the pointers are pointing at string literals. You've essentially answered the question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assesment is correct.  You're creating an array of `char *` and initializing those pointers the the address of string constants, and string constants cannot be modified.

Instead of defining an array of `char *`, define a 2D array of `char`.  While you use string constants to initialize the array, the array itself it writable.

```
char strings_array[][50] = {
    "First string",
    "213123Second_string3",
    "",
    "-3",
    "s",
};
```

Note that for a multidimensional array, only the first dimension can have the size omitted if there is an initializer.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake that popped out at me was that in `Memset` you indirectly cast a `void*` to `unsigned char *`. I would change this to an explicit cast: `unsigned char *string = (unsigned char *)str;`

Secondly, you are absolutely correct: string literals cannot be modified. An attempt to modify a string literal would result in an error.

To test this code, I would try to allocate a string array on the heap, load some test strings into there, and then pass your string pointers from that array into your Memset function.